# How do I insert values into existing rows in SQL server in default asp.net mvc project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, insert

I have opened visual studio and created a new default mvc asp.net 4 project. And this is my database table data after adding few extra columns(that I want to use) as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Updated Question:

Basically I used a default mvc project and in the default database, I added few extra columns and also in my register view from account controller class, I added extra html content to let the users add extra information for the extra columns that I added like FirstName, LastName etc. Now the problem is that only my email and password is getting stored. So where do I add database code that tells that whatever the user enters in the form, must be added to the database.

Here is the form and here are the details that got added. In this picture I am clicking Register button.

[image]

Now in my database, only email and password got added.

[image]

Of course I only added html content for "FirstName", "LastName" etc. So where do I make these changes so that they get added to my database as well?

And I did add properties for my "FirstName" etc in my RegisterView model.

Comment: Do you have the user enter any of that information, or are you just going to populate it for them with a "best guess"?

Comment: Well you have to check what columns are nullable first. If your ID doesn't use AUTO_INCREMENT then you will have a problem.

Comment: @Ingenioushax I just want my details to be added to my database. I am just learning so I am not concerned about designing a good application or whatever as of now. So I have views setup where users enter their details like email, password, firstname etc and I want them to be added to my database.

Comment: I believe the answer is something extremely simple, let me re-fix my question, I guess I did not explain properly.

Comment: @Blasttrash judging from the code that you had posted earlier, you should have an ApplicationUser class defined somewhere in your application.  Can you post that class?

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that you have to find where your `ApplicationUser` class is defined, and modify the properties there

It might look something like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

To add a first name, simply add this

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

---

you also have to actually populate the values in your user as you create it.

change this:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

to this

```
var user = new ApplicationUser 
{ 
    UserName = model.Email, 
    Email = model.Email,
    FirstName = model.FirstName, 
    //etc...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the data to be stored in the database, and you're going to write the query yourself as you're doing, then you'll need to do something like the following:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AspNetUsers (email, emailconfirmed, passwordhash, securitystamp, phonenumber, ..., firstname, lastname, gender, aboutuser) VALUES ('email@email.com', '1', a hash, securitystampValue, '555-666-5555', ..., 'Ingenious', 'hax', 1, 'some description';"))
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And you'll want to use paramaterized values as Tony Morris did in his post.

If you want to update the table with the new information, it's very similar.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AspNetUsers SET firstname = 'ingenious', lastname='hax', gender=1, aboutuser='some description about the user' WHERE firstname='ingenious';");
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```